# Writing Large Pandas Dataframe to Postgres

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I have a largish csv file I need to load into Postgres. I am using pandas to do this.

My csv file is around 500,000 rows, and 30 columns. Loading the file into a dataframe is no problem, but importing it into Postgres is very slow. Currently I am using this code to do it:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    '/home/data/data.txt', 
    sep='|', 
    dtype=object,
)
print('loaded data')

df.to_sql(
    name='table', 
    con=engine, 
    schema='public', 
    method='multi', 
    index=False, 
    if_exists='replace', 
    chunksize=10_000
)
print('imported {} rows'.format(len(df)))
```

Comment: Does it have to be imported into pandas first?  Can you just use \COPY in psql?

Comment: Maybe you could split the dataframe in smaller chunks, write it to sql utilizing multi threading and concatenating it back together afterwards if you want to use pandas?

Comment: @AlanPear How much slow it is? seconds ? minutes?

Comment: @Jeremy The file won't be on the same machine as postgres.

Comment: @Mibi isn't that what the chunksize param is doing in to_sql?

Comment: @Poojan about 20 minutes

Comment: Checkout this link http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/perf.html. I think you will find it helpful. to_sql is not most optimized way to insert large data and as it turns out many others faced similar issues when inserting large df. `odo` uses SQLAlchemy in backend. I highly suggest you to check out this module.

Comment: You can see the write speed comparisions in the link. `odo` is 50MB/s compared to `pandas` 3-5MB/s. Which is around 10-15x Speedup atleast. Also checkout this github post https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15276.

Comment: @AlanPear It doesn't have to be on the same machine to use \COPY in psql.